# How to send e-mail with std.net.curl?

Tags: email, smtp, d

I tried to use example (with my login and pass) from http://dlang.org/phobos/std_net_curl.html#.SMTP

But every time I am getting error: `std.net.curl.CurlException@std\net\curl.d(3691): Failed sending data to the peer on handle 7F6D08`.
What's wrong? I tried to specify port (465) but it's not helped.

```
import std.net.curl;

// Send an email with SMTPS
auto smtp = SMTP("smtps://smtp.gmail.com");
smtp.setAuthentication("from.addr@gmail.com", "password");
smtp.mailTo = ["<to.addr@gmail.com>"];
smtp.mailFrom = "<from.addr@gmail.com>";
smtp.message = "Example Message";
smtp.perform();
```

Comment: Does your password have a colon in it? That can mess up curl (it doesn't handle that or a few other characters properly). Also might be an ssl library thing on Windows, I'm not sure. I've also seen this message happen if your computer clock is more than five minutes wrong (with Amazon SES rather than Gmail but could be a problem with it too). But I'd check the clock and try another account with an all alphanumeric password to rule those out first if you have one.

Comment: Adam, thanks for answer, now I understand that it's better go with vibed. It's more usable than std.net.curl. Now I am trying to figure how to work with them

Comment: I had a similar problem with JavaMail the other day, but I am not sure it was caused by the same thing. I solved it by applying the modifications described in the following link : https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255, but I ended up restoring the changes because it isn't secure.

In reality this is a workaround more than anything else, this method of authentication is now considered obsolete by Google's standards.